# QR with column pivoting

Tags: algorithms, numerical-linear-algebra

Golub and van Loan's algorithm 5.4.1
for QR factorization is suitable as a rank revealing algorithm.
The results are R, Q with the subdiagonal elements stored in "factored form" and the column ordering. 
Now can anyone help in the technique to take the Q from factored form to complete matrix. To give some additional information.

I used the following data (in Matlab style)

```
data= [ 1     2     3
        4     5     6
        7     8     9
       10    11    12
       13    14    15
       16    17    18];
```

Matlab call
[Q R P]=qr(data,0)

produces

```
Q =
   -0.1048   -0.7161    0.6559
   -0.2097   -0.5013   -0.5460
   -0.3145   -0.2864   -0.4138
   -0.4193   -0.0716   -0.0753
   -0.5241    0.1432    0.2966
   -0.6290    0.3581    0.0827

R =
  -28.6182  -24.2154  -26.4168
         0    2.1483    1.0742
         0         0    0.0000

p = 3     1     2
```

but my own attempt to implement this produces

```
Q= 
0.10483        0              0
0.209657       0.0025         0
0.314485       0.184241       0.81162
0.419314       0.365981       0.398879
0.524142       0.54772       -0.0138585
0.628971       0.729459      -0.426595
```

while the R matches

```
-28.6182    -24.2154    -26.4168
  0           2.1483      1.0742
  0           0           0
```

The 2nd and 3rd columns of my Q seem to show a linear relationship with those from Matlab. Is there a way the Q results can be transformed to match those of Matlab ?

Comment: Never mind, I reimplemented based on http://faculty.nps.edu/borges/Teaching/MA3046/Matlab/qrlsdiary.html and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

The [LAPACK documentation](https://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node40.html) of the QR algorithm (without pivoting) says the following:

> The matrix Q is not formed explicitly, but is represented as a product of elementary reflectors, as described in section [5.4](https://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node128.html#secorthog). Users need not be aware of the details of this representation, because associated routines are provided to work with Q: xORGQR (or xUNGQR in the complex case) can generate all or part of Q, while xORMQR (or xUNMQR) can pre- or post-multiply a given matrix by Q or QT (QH if complex).

I think that you can check against those routines.